# Network Discovery via datagram sockets: Multicasting

Tags: java, multicast, datagram

I'm implementing the example where a server listens for any active clients in the network.

I'm using Datagram sockets for the server to do the multicast and clients to respon to the server.

```
public void run() {

    try {
        byte[] recvBuf = new byte[15000];
        DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(recvBuf, recvBuf.length);
        DatagramSocket dSock = new DatagramSocket(4445);
        dSock.receive(packet);
        int byteCount = packet.getLength();
        ByteArrayInputStream byteStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(recvBuf);
        ObjectInputStream is = new ObjectInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(byteStream));
        }
```

}

and on the client's side:

```
public void run() {
    {
     ObjectOutputStream os = null;
        try {
            InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByName("Server's IP");//Note!
            ByteArrayOutputStream byteStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream(15000);
            os = new ObjectOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(byteStream));
            os.flush();
              os.flush();
            byte[] sendBuf = byteStream.toByteArray();
            DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(sendBuf, sendBuf.length, address, 4445);
            int byteCount = packet.getLength();
            }
     }
```

}

In the above Eg, the Client has to know the server's IP apriori(hardcode). How can I modify the code on the server's side so that the server sends it's IP to the client and client responds to it?

I was able to do this using sockets but is it possible using datagram sockets?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [DatgramPacket.getAddress()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/DatagramPacket.html#getAddress%28%29) and reply to the sender

> Returns the IP address of the machine to which this datagram is being sent or from which the datagram was received.

Comment: @peterlawrey- You're asking me to get the IP from the Server's side and send it to the client as the datagram?

Comment: your don't have servers and clients with datagrams, only senders and receivers. A receiver can reply to the IP which sent it a packet.

Comment: Ok, I don't get it. How does the server know the client's IP without the explicit sending? Only after DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(sendBuf, sendBuf.length, address, 4445); has been executed(which needs address) I can find out packet.getAddress.

Comment: You only know the other ends IP after to receive a packet from it. At that point you know the senders IP.

Comment: Multi-cast UDP is used for service discovery, there is nothing automagical which happens before you use it to give you service discovery.

Comment: It can be used for network discovery, but you have to actually do something (like send a packet)

Answer (score 0):

Try getting `hostAddress` using `InetAddress.getHostAddress`, read the IP part and pass it to a variable.

```
InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByName("[variable]");
```

or

```
InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByAddress("[variable]");
```

I hope any of these would lead to a better way.